# how to access Native HTML Input element using formControl in Angular 2.0

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-forms, onfocus, angular2-formbuilder

I'm using Angular 2.0 final release.

**What i want to do?**
- i want to show some notifications (warnings, the requirements for the input) only when the input receive focus. Or even better, when his parent (`the div`) has `mouse hover` event.

Doing this from the parent(the div) is easy. Just (focus)=showNotifications() + an ngIf - and the job is done.

**But i want to encapsulate this functionality inside the show-notifications component - and make it reusable..**

Given that i pass `the control` inside the show-notifications using `@Input()` - i could do both this things if i have access to the `native HTML input element`.You can see how in `show-notifications.component.ts`. Here is the code:

**app.component.html:**

```
`<div>
   <label>Name: </label>
   <input formControlName="myName">
   <show-notifications [the_control]="myName" ></show-notifications>
</div>`
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
export class AppComponent {
    myName = new FormControl("defaultvalue",[some validators..])
}
```

**show-notifications.component.html:**

```
<div class="show_requirements" *ngIf="hasfocus or parentDivHasMouseHover"> // incorect code and logic - i know, but you can see the idea..

    <p *ngFor="let requirement of thisInputRequirements">{{requirement}}<p>

</div>
```

**show-notifications.component.ts:**

```
export class ShowNotificationsComponent {

    @Input() the_control;
    this.thisInputRequirements = // take them form firebase.
    this.thisInputCustomErrorMessages = // take them from firebase.

    // I implemented all this and works amazing but i want to do:

    //something like this:

    ngOnInit(){
        this.nativeInputElement = this.the_control.getNativeElement() // this of course doesn't work

        // the requirements are shown only when the input receive focus
        let source = Rx.DOM.focus(this.nativeInputElement);
        source.subscribe( x => this.hasFocus = true)

        // Or even better: 
        // the requirements are shown only when the parent has mouse hover
        // or any other event / endles posibilites here..

        let parent = getParentOf(this.nativeInputElement)
        let source = Rx.DOM.mouseover(parent);
        source.subscribe( x => this.parentDivHasMouseHover = true) // this will be some toggling functionality.
    }

}
```

**Question:**

***How do i access the native element given that i have the formControl (myName = the_control)  object?***

Is there a better way to do notifications in a separate component - and make it reusable? I already use this successfully throughout my entire app - to show errors and input requirements..

Note: I tried to pass the hole html input first using hashtag syntax ( #myInput ) and form there, inside the show-notifications component, i tried to do: myInput.myName - to acces the control but i get undefined. The controls are not present on the native input element. And I need that control for validation:)

Comment: One option would be to create a custom form control. You could let the user pass in the HTML with a #input so you can bind it to the `ControlValueAccessor` field to be used.

Answer (score 4):

I think you could use `#` notation to pass the element to `ShowNotificationsComponent`:

```
export class ShowNotificationsComponent {
    @Input() the_control;
    @Input() elm;
    //...
}
```

Then in the template:

```
<input formControlName="myName" #elm>
<show-notifications [the_control]="myName" [elm]="elm"></show-notifications>
```

Comment: Yes @Martin, thanks for the answer, I already did that, and works fine but still,  i'm waiting for a solution that allows me to access the native element form inside the control. I can't believe they are not tied together in some way. Form the native input element i can't get the control. From the control i can't get the native element. How could this be? It doesn't sound right. I need to create all those # variables all over my code. Not clean. But yeah, works for now :)

Comment: Well, if you look into the source code for `FormControl` and `AbstractControl` it actually doesn't access the native element anywhere. See https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.1.0-beta.0/modules/%40angular/forms/src/model.ts#L76-L608 and https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.1.0-beta.0/modules/%40angular/forms/src/model.ts#L608-L798

Comment: So I'm not totally sure, but isn't the `name` attribute of the `nativeElement` what's being used in Template-Driven forms to name the FormControl in the FormGroup? If so (using your favorite DOM selector, I choose jQuery as it's what I know off the top of my head) do the following... `var element = $('[name={{ yourInputName }}]');` after which time you should be able to access it as a standard input form element.

Comment: @Alon did you ever find an Angular way to do this, as I also don't want to be plastering #name's all over my templates either just for a custom component to access the dom element?

Answer (score 0):

I found something that may be helpfull if you want to get some information from the Abstractcontrol as it was a normal Html Input Element, for example if you want to add a "Event Listener" to it, in order to know when user is interacting with the element, It could be done by using the valueChanges or statusChanges, both Observables from class AbstractControl, i used it to know when a  element has changed and get the option selected to do more actions before the form is submited,  I leave here my code example:

```
getValue() {
  this.myForm.get('myControlName').valueChanges.subscribe((optionValue) => {
    console.log(optionValue);
    this.doSomething(optionValue);
  });
}
```

And if you want to made some animation or changes when the user hover the parent maybe you can use some simple css trick like this:

```
.parent #child{
  opacity: 0;
}

.parent:hover #child{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

You can check this documentation for more details : https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#valueChanges

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, the only way for an element to have access to its sibling is to pass a reference to it. You ***could*** give your notifications component the name of the control and the form and look it up, as you are doing, but it's an error prone process. However, I think creating a directive would be more helpful to solve your situation. You can use that directive right on the input. It allows your code to be reusable like a component, but because it is actually on the input, it can have access to the native html element. Here is an example using a currency input I wrote, to get a feel for what to do. I added a spot for the focus event to show you where to do stuff. Obviously, you'd want to change the name and erase the code with the decimal pipe, but I left it for reference.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appCurrencyInput]',
})
export class CurrencyInputDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input() runOnEveryModelChange = false;

  public reference: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;
  private numTimesRan = 0;
  constructor(el: ElementRef, private decimalPipe: DecimalPipe) {
    this.reference = el;
  }

  @HostListener('focus', ['$event'])
  private onFocus = (focusEvent: FocusEvent) => {
    //You could do showNotifications() here, have access to focusEvent if you want
  }

  @HostListener('ngModelChange', ['$event'])
  private onModelChange = (ngModelChangeEvent: number) => {
    this.numTimesRan++;
    if (this.runOnEveryModelChange || this.numTimesRan === 1) {
      const asNumber = this.decimalPipe.transform(ngModelChangeEvent, '1.2-2');
      this.reference.nativeElement.value = asNumber ? asNumber.replace(/,/g, '') : null;
    }
  };

  ngOnInit() {
    //here you could do something if you want, just like a component
  }
}
```

And you would use it like so

```
<input formControlName="myName" appCurrencyInput>
```

Answer (score -3):

This is very Basic. FormContrl is not required.
you should create a local variable on input element with # and
pass local variables to method

```
<div>
<label for="firstname">First Name</label>
<input name="fname" #nameFirst />
<label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
<input name="lname" #nameLast />
</div>
<button (click)="send(nameFirst , nameLast)">Submit</button>

export class HtmlExample {

    send(firstName: HTMLInputElement, lastName: HTMLInputElement): void {
        console.log(`Hello ${firstName.value}  ${lastName.value}`);
        firstName.value = '';
        lastName.value = '';
    }

}
```